# OnConnected and OnDisconnected events fires twice ¿?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, signalr

In the following code when i connect or disconnect clients, the event OnConnected and Disconnected fires twice. How to avoid this?
I have the last version of all the components.

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Cors
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
Imports Owin
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim url As String = "http://localhost:8080/arc/"
        WebApp.Start(url)
    End Sub
End Class
Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
        app.MapSignalR()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class MyHub
    Inherits Hub
    Public Sub Send(name As String, message As String)
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function OnConnected() As Task
        Debug.Print("Client connected: " + Context.ConnectionId)
        Return MyBase.OnConnected()
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function OnDisconnected(stopCalled As Boolean) As Task
        Debug.Print("Client DISconnected: " + Context.ConnectionId)
        Return MyBase.OnDisconnected(True)
    End Function
   End Class
```

---

The client code in Vb.net is as follow:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs

Partial Public Class MainWindow
    Inherits Window
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public connection As HubConnection = New HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/arc/")
    Public myHub As IHubProxy

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        DataContext = Me
        connection = New HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/arc/")

        myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("myHub")
        myHub.On(Of String)("addMessage", AddressOf addMessage)
    End Sub

    Async Sub btnShowSignal_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Await connection.Start()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Show your client code

Comment: Question edited and added client code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One day, my mvc methods were firing 2 times (not signalr, my pages were).

I researched it and i found this :

Remove your favicon (in html head) from your layout (masterpage) if it is coming with 404 error code. Check your favicon from your browser's console if it comes with 404.

I dont know what relation each other. But it was solution for me in that day.

Just an idea.

Comment: 1 idea > 0 idea